# Header is not rendered properly when using datatables in accordion menu?

Tags: jquery, datatables

In the following image table header is not rendered properly. jQuery Dtatables is shown in accordion menu.

[image: Screenshot]

My code is shown below:

```js
$('#'+initId).DataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "scrollY": "260px",
    "scrollCollapse": true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION**

You need to handle event when content is shown and call [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29) and [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API methods in the event handler. This will recalculate the column widths after a change in the display.

```js
$('#'+initId).DataTable()
    .columns.adjust()
    .responsive.recalc();
```

See [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29) and [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API methods for more information.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/Ltga3n4u/) for code and demonstration.

> **LINKS**

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solution to the most common problems with jQuery DataTables and Bootstrap Tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gyrocode, but i need to implement these on accordion menu. how to redraw the datatable, to fix headers. if i use ur code means, it will show .responsive.recalc() is undefined

Answer (score 1):

its working fine for me :)

```
function tableInitialize(initId){
  table = $('#'+initId).DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "scrollY": "260px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "responsive":true
  });   
  $('#div').click(function(){
    table.columns.adjust()
         //.responsive.recalc();
  });}
```